# Duplicating a group - (right now it just puts it as a sub group when you do)

Tags: objects, workflow

First you make a group from 3 items. When you select the "entire group" when duplicating, the following happens:

[image]

The items are not in a new group. I can understand that when you copy items inside a group, you want them to stay inside. However, it would be good if you could select the entire group specifically, and copy it in its entirety.

Am i missing something?

If not, is there a quicker way then instead of having to remove them first, then adding them to a separate new group?  It gets very tedious after a while

Comment: It isn't clear enough what's the problem. If you want to organize a scene using groups, create one from some objects and add it *as a group instance* (`Shift`+`A` > *Group Instance*), not by duplicating. To select all the elements of the group use `Shift`+`G` > *Group*.

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible *smile*. When duplicating an entire group. It does not duplicate the group. it only duplicates the items and keeps them inside the same group.

Comment: I really don't know how i can be more clear :P  
Duplicate a group just like in photoshop for example, where it makes a Group (2) with all its contents inside.

Comment: In Blender you don't *duplicate* group to make objects from group to be repeated across the scene. You add *instance* of a group by pressing `Shift`+`A` > "Name of group". If you want to create *completely another group* Group2 which could be edited independetly from Group1 then you create another group either by `Ctrl`+`G` or in Properties Editor > Object tab.

Answer (score 0):

After using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate the group it will indeed create those ugly copies. No, go to *Objects > Group > Remove From All Groups*. Then just regroup them.

All the objects of interest should've stayed selected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you select a group and then you try to hit Ctrl + D. 
It duplicates all the object but puts it inside the same Group.

To fix this try to copy/past e(Ctrl C, Ctrl V) after selecting the group. 
It will then duplicate the group

[image]

This worked for me. Hope it helps.